# Varnish - https and external redirects

Tags: varnish

Hello I have a proxy setup with pound and varnish, the domain runs on SSL so all requests are redirected to https:// with https enabled, i.e. if I remove the config I have a redirect to paypal that works 100%. However with Https on it won't work.

I havn't been able to workout why this is happening, the response from the web server works and has location: https://externalsite.com set, but when it gets to the client it has been changed to the original site.

```
Client - Varnish https://example.com
Web Server - Varnish Location https://externalsite.com/path
Varnish - Client Location https://example.com/path
```

Any help would be appreciated, will keep looking in the meantime.,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and discovered that it was pound that was causing the redirect back to the original domain.

Adding the following setting to /etc/pound/pound.cfg fixed the issue for me.

```
 RewriteLocation 0
```

Comment: Thanks, will need to test this out.